# No intellisense in markup (.aspx, .ascx) files in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Lately, the intellisense for markup in Visual Studio 2010 has stopped working for me. It still works in the code-behinds, but nothing ever pops up when editing the server-side controls in the .aspx and .ascx files.

Also, I can jump from .aspx to .aspx.cs with F7, but I can't jump back to the .aspx any more.

What have I done?

Answer (score 0):

Please check 
Options > Text Editor > Select Language > Statement completion > 
**Auto list members & Parameter Information (Checked)**

above boxes should remain checked,otherwise intellisense box won't appear.

In order to show intellisense dialog press CTRL + J

Best Regards
Myra